# Can't resolve windows domains in local network

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns, dhcp

I've installed ubuntu on my computer at work because I think it is a perfect system for work which I do but I got some issues. I can't resolve domains from windows DNS server. Basically, we have two servers, one is Windows server (DNS sever) and another one is ubuntu 12.04 (LAMP). So every time when I create new project I have to create new alias on DNS server for example *project1.localdomain.local* which points to ubuntu server. On ubuntu server I have to create the project in directory /var/www/project1/htdocs. Everything works for computers in local network with windows or for macs. So basically when I am trying open a link http://project1.localdomain.local in a browser it works. But when I do it on my computer with fresh ubuntu installation it doesn't. It looks like ubuntu can't resolve local domain where DNS server is.

So my network looks like that:
10.10.16.1 - DNS server - windows server
domain - test

I've already tried resolved the problem adding lines to /etc/resolve.conf file

```
domain test
nameserver 10.10.16.2
```

/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file I commented out line

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf I added lines

```
supersede domain-name "test";
prepend domain-name-servers 10.10.16.1, 10.10.16.2;
```

But it doesn't work.

On windows or mac I don't have to do any additional configuration to make it work.

This is the contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: Hi Sneetsher, this is the contents: inline `code in backticks`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change hosts line:

```
hosts:          files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4
```

`.local` is used by mDNS (Avahi), `dns` should comes first.

See http://www.lowlevelmanager.com/2011/09/fix-linux-dns-issues-with-local.html

Comment: It was exactly that, thank you very much Sneetsher, you save me a lot of time.