# DNS Resolution Problem on Ubuntu 14.4 LTS

Tags: networking, virtualbox, resolution, dns

I have a Windows 8 host machine running VirtualBox and a running a Ubuntu 14.4 LTS Virtual  Machine.

In the Ubuntu VM, I can access and resolve DNS for every external site (Ex.: www.google.com) and I can resolve intranet sites by first name, ex.: anothermachine.

If I use the full qualified domain name, like anothermachine.mywindowsdomain.local, which is valid on the windows, this name can't be resolved inside the Ubuntu VM.

This box was created by vagrant.

This box is using NetworkManager.

I'm using `ping` to check if the host name is being resolved. Doing a `ping` mybox works and doing a ping mybox.mydomain.local don't work. Both approaches works for any other machine on the same network.

resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.0.2.3
```

nsswitch.conf

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
```

Comment: `.local` is actually appended by `mDNS` or `avahi-daemon` in Ubuntu. You should find the machine by `anothermachine.local`

Comment: I can't find by anothermachine.local, even tough, it is very odd... It should find the machine with the same full qualified domain name that it is found by other machines in the same network...

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?  Do you set up your machine with `/etc/network/interfaces` or NetworkManager?  Add the contents of those files to your question.  How do you resolve the names?  Use `getent host name` or `getent ahost name` to see what your programs resolves to.

Comment: @Anders, I've edited with the information you asked for. The only think I didn't know how to do is the getent...

Comment: @EricLemes, just open a terminal emulation window and type in the string in the command prompt.

Comment: @Anders "unknown database" is the answer

Comment: Ok, if you look into the `man`  page of `getent`(1), you will see that I remembered wrong, it is `hosts` and `ahosts` and not `host`.  So `getent hosts www.google.com`, `getent hosts 216.58.209.100` and `getent ahosts www.google.com` will tell you what names you are able to find.

Comment: getent hosts www.google.com returns 4 IP addresses. getent hosts anothermachine returno 1 IP address. getent hosts anothermachine.domain.local returns no result. getent hosts 216.58.209.100 returns no result. Similar, but more details for "ahosts". The same commands that do not return results for hosts also don't return results for ahosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as a duplicate of [Can't resolve windows domains in local network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414277/cant-resolve-windows-domains-in-local-network/).

`.local` is handled by mDNS (Avahi or Bonjour) before trying with regular DNS server. mDNS should resolve name in the form of `machinename.local` if it does not get it, it returns `NOT FOUND`.

Where what you are using is `anothermachine.mywindowsdomain.local`. `.local` here is part of the full qualified domain name `mywindowsdomain.local` that should be resolved using DNS.

- Change name resolving priority list in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to:

  ```
  hosts:          files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]
  ```
- Otherway change MS domain to something different, example: `mywindowsdomain.loc`

**Reference:** [Fix linux DNS issues with .local addresses on MS domain](http://www.lowlevelmanager.com/2011/09/fix-linux-dns-issues-with-local.html)